# Switching ActiveTestSuite to JUnit4 with annotations

Tags: java, junit, junit4

I have created a some testcases and use an ActiveTestSuite to run the methods in parallel to check out some potential threading issues.    Next, I wanted to swap the class over to JUnit4 with the annotation because I need to take advantage of the @BeforeClass and @AfterClass annotations.   My problem comes in with creating the test suite.   Previously, I did the following

```
public static Test suite() {
       TestSuite suite = new ActiveTestSuite(
              MultithreadedTests.class.getName());
       // the parm is the method name!!!
       suite.addTest(new MultithreadedTests("testTransferToHostStockCountAndFinFile"));
       suite.addTest(new MultithreadedTests("testTransferToHostRTVAndFinFile"));
       suite.addTest(new MultithreadedTests("testTransferToHostTRFAndFinFile"));
       suite.addTest(new MultithreadedTests("testTransferToHostRCVAndFinFile"));
       suite.addTest(new MultithreadedTests("testTransferToHostCartonAndFinFile"));
       suite.addTest(new MultithreadedTests("testTransferToHostInvAdjustmentAndFinFile"));
       suite.addTest(new MultithreadedTests("testTransferToHostStoreOrderAndFinFile"));
       return suite;
}
```

In order to get the Before/After class parts working, my test class no longer extends TestCase, otherwise those methods where not getting triggered.  I can get my class compiled doing something like this:

```
package com.jda.portfolio.hostexport.server.exporthandler;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({ com.jda.portfolio.hostexport.server.exporthandler.TestThreadedExportHandler.class  })
public class AllTests {}
```

But the tests get single-threaded, which is not what I want. I need to be able to run each of the testcase methods in a separate thread but I am having a hard time understanding how to use the JUnit4 annotations to create the suite such that it is an ‘ActiveTestSuite’.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveTestSuite seems to be still available as part of junit 4 in the package "junit.extensions".

There are also some third party extensions which do similar things. I have used a variant of [these 3 classes](http://mycila.googlecode.com/svn/sandbox/src/main/java/com/mycila/sandbox/junit/runner/) in one of my projects successfully. Also the discussion about [Concurrent JUnit Tests With RunnerScheduler](http://java.dzone.com/articles/concurrent-junit-tests) sounds like a possible solution.

Comment: It is still available but it misses some example how to use the ActiveTestSuite with annotated tests if we do not want to add third party libraries/classes.